# Get woocommerce json order metadata key values ​with google apps script (REST API)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am connecting my woocommerce store with Google Sheets to sync orders via REST API and google apps script (with Customer key & Client secret key).
The connection is correct and the data is synchronizing well.
The problem I have is that I want to synchronize some specific meta_data order and try as I try, I can't.

Here the Json Data: https://pastebin.com/Q3zkm4rW

Specifically I want to get the value of this order meta_data:

```
 "key": "_wccf_of_fecha_envio"
 "key": "_wccf_of_empresa_mensajeria" 
 "key": "_wccf_of_numseguimiento_pedido" 
 "key": "_wcpdf_invoice_date_formatted" 
 "key": "_wcpdf_invoice_number"
 "key": "seguimiento" (in this option the 3 values, transportista, codigo, fecha).
```

How can I get the metadata values ​​mentioned above?
I'm new to javascript and sometimes I can't find the solution on my own. I have looked through google and stackoverflow but although I have seen similar cases and tried to replicate the case, I have not succeeded.

All help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

This is my google apps script complete code:

```
function start_syncv2() {
    var sheet_name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Pedidos2');
    fetch_orders(sheet_name)
}



function fetch_orders(sheet_name) {

    var ck = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Ajustes').getRange("C10").getValue();
    var cs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Ajustes').getRange("C11").getValue();
    var website = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Ajustes').getRange("C9").getValue();
    var manualDate = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Ajustes').getRange("C12").getValue(); 
    var m = new Date(manualDate).toISOString();
    var surl = website + "/wp-json/wc/v2/orders?consumer_key=" + ck + "&consumer_secret=" + cs + "&after=" + m + "&per_page=100"; 
    var url = surl
    Logger.log(url)

    var options =

        {
            "method": "GET",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
            "muteHttpExceptions": true,

        };

    var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

    Logger.log(result.getResponseCode())
    if (result.getResponseCode() == 200) {

        var params = JSON.parse(result.getContentText());
        Logger.log(result.getContentText());

    }

    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    var temp = doc.getSheetByName(sheet_name);

    var consumption = {};

    var arrayLength = params.length;
    Logger.log(arrayLength)
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        Logger.log("dfsfsdfsf")
        var a,c,d,n,o;
        var container = [];


        n = params[i]["meta_data"].length;
        var numFactura = "";
        var fechaFactura = "";
        var fechaEnvio = "";
        var mensajeria = "";
        var numSeguimiento = "";

          for (var h = 0; h < n; h++) {
            var key;
              key = params[i]["meta_data"][h]["key"];
              o = params[i]["key"].length;
                for (var n = 0; n < o; n++) {
                  numFactura = params[i]["meta_data"][h]["key"][n]["_wcpdf_invoice_number"];
                  fechaFactura = params[i]["meta_data"][h]["key"][n]["_wcpdf_invoice_date_formatted"];
                  fechaEnvio = params[i]["meta_data"][h]["key"][n]["_wccf_of_fecha_envio"];
                  mensajeria = params[i]["meta_data"][h]["key"][n]["_wccf_of_empresa_mensajeria"];
                  numSeguimiento = params[i]["meta_data"][h]["key"][n]["_wccf_of_numseguimiento_pedido"];
                }                        
          }

        a = container.push(numFactura);
        a = container.push(fechaFactura);
        a = container.push(fechaEnvio);
        a = container.push(mensajeria);
        a = container.push(numSeguimiento);


        a = container.push(params[i]["number"]); // Nº Pedido
        a = container.push(params[i]["date_created"]);  // Fecha pedido
        a = container.push(params[i]["status"]); // Estado del pedido


        a = container.push(params[i]["billing"]["first_name"] + " " + params[i]["billing"]["last_name"]);  // Nombre y apellidos del cliente
        Logger.log(a)

        a = container.push(params[i]["billing"]["email"]);  // Email

        a = container.push(params[i]["subtotal"]); // Subtotal

        var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

        var temp = doc.getSheetByName('Pedidos2');

        temp.appendRow(container);
     
        removeDuplicates(sheet_name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should no iterate `params[i]["meta_data"][h]["key"]`.

Instead it is a value or object you want to append to the sheet.

By the way, there is something missing on your json sample.

I have tried to recover it in my example.

```js
const params = sample();
const i = 0;

const target = ['_wccf_of_fecha_envio',  '_wccf_of_empresa_mensajeria', '_wccf_of_numseguimiento_pedido', '_wcpdf_invoice_date_formatted', '_wcpdf_invoice_number', {'seguimiento': ['transportista', 'codigo', 'fecha']}];
/* for loop of params */
const meta_data = {};
for (const e of params[i]['meta_data'])  {
  meta_data[e.key] = e.value;
}
console.log(meta_data);

var container = [];
for (const key of target) {
  if (typeof key === 'object') {
    const k = Object.keys(key)[0];
    const values = meta_data[k];
    if (!values) {
      container.push([...new Array(key[k].length)]);
      continue; 
    }
    for (const value of key[k]) {
      container.push(meta_data[k][value] || '');
    }
  }
  else {
    container.push(meta_data[key] || '');
  }
}
console.log(container);

/* sample json for test */
function sample() {
  return [{"id":3506,"parent_id":0,"number":"134","order_key":"wc_order_2V3MYLlkjasd887","created_via":"checkout","version":"3.5.7","status":"completed","currency":"EUR","date_created":"2019-05-31T19:56:21","date_created_gmt":"2019-05-31T18:56:21","date_modified":"2020-12-30T20:32:00","date_modified_gmt":"2020-12-30T19:32:00","discount_total":"0.00","discount_tax":"0.00","shipping_total":"4.55","shipping_tax":"0.00","cart_tax":"0.00","total":"13.81","total_tax":"0.00","prices_include_tax":true,"customer_id":0,"customer_ip_address":"83.XX.XX.XXX","customer_user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.1.0; SM-J710F) AppleWebKit/XXX.XX (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.XXXX.XXX Mobile Safari/XXX.XX","customer_note":"llamar al XXXXXXXXX pues trabajo en la misma poblacion","billing":{"first_name":"Mari XXXX","last_name":"LorXXX XXXXX","company":"","address_1":"c/ de los Amigos, nº 1","address_2":"","city":"Ciudad de los Amigos","state":"V","postcode":"46XXX","country":"ES","email":"mxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com","phone":"6XXXXXXXX"},"shipping":{"first_name":"Mari XXXX","last_name":"LorXXX XXXXX","company":"","address_1":"c/ de los Amigos, nº 1","address_2":"","city":"Ciudad de los Amigos","state":"V","postcode":"46XXX","country":"ES"},"payment_method":"stripe","payment_method_title":"Tarjeta de crédito/débito","transaction_id":"ch_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","date_paid":"2019-08-28T19:56:25","date_paid_gmt":"2019-08-28T18:56:25","date_completed":"2019-08-29T00:35:16","date_completed_gmt":"2019-08-29T23:35:16","cart_hash":"eafxxxxXXXXXxxxxxXXXXXXxxxx30cb","meta_data":[{"id":365723,"key":"_wcson_order_number","value":"134"},{"id":365724,"key":"klaviyo-response","value":{"headers":[],"body":"","response":{"code":false,"message":false},"cookies":[],"http_response":null}},{"id":365725,"key":"terms","value":"on"},{"id":365726,"key":"aniley_checkout_privacy_policy","value":"on"},{"id":365727,"key":"_stripe_source_id","value":"src_1ExxxxxXXXXXXXXXxxxxxxXXXXXXXxxwk"},{"id":365728,"key":"_stripe_charge_captured","value":"yes"},{"id":365729,"key":"_stripe_fee","value":"0.48"},{"id":365730,"key":"_stripe_net","value":"16.23"},{"id":365731,"key":"_stripe_currency","value":"EUR"},{"id":365811,"key":"aniley_nifcif","value":""},{"id":366541,"key":"_vc_post_settings","value":{"vc_grid_id":[]}},{"id":366573,"key":"_wccf_of_cuenta_instagramm","value":""},{"id":366574,"key":"_wccf_of_id_cuenta_instagramm","value":"1629"},{"id":366575,"key":"_wccf_of_data_cuenta_instagramm","value":[]},{"id":366576,"key":"_wccf_of_order_devolucionproductos","value":""},{"id":366577,"key":"_wccf_of_id_order_devolucionproductos","value":"809"},{"id":366578,"key":"_wccf_of_data_order_devolucionproductos","value":[]},{"id":366579,"key":"_wccf_of_fecha_envio","value":"29/9/2019"},{"id":366580,"key":"_wccf_of_id_fecha_envio","value":"477"},{"id":366581,"key":"_wccf_of_data_fecha_envio","value":[]},{"id":366582,"key":"_wccf_of_empresa_mensajeria","value":"Correos Express"},{"id":366583,"key":"_wccf_of_id_empresa_mensajeria","value":"788"},{"id":366584,"key":"_wccf_of_data_empresa_mensajeria","value":[]},{"id":366585,"key":"_wccf_of_order_envio_bultos","value":"1"},{"id":366586,"key":"_wccf_of_id_order_envio_bultos","value":"795"},{"id":366587,"key":"_wccf_of_data_order_envio_bultos","value":[]},{"id":366588,"key":"_wccf_of_numseguimiento_pedido","value":"3522XXXXXXXXXXXXX50"},{"id":366589,"key":"_wccf_of_id_numseguimiento_pedido","value":"458"},{"id":366590,"key":"_wccf_of_data_numseguimiento_pedido","value":[]},{"id":366591,"key":"_wccf_of_seguir_paquete","value":"<a href=\"https://s.correosexpress.com/search?shippingNumber=3522XXXXXXXXXXXXX50\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color: #626262;text-decoration: none;padding: 10px 15%;font-weight: 600;\">VER EL ESTADO DE MI PEDIDO</a>"},{"id":366592,"key":"_wccf_of_id_seguir_paquete","value":"428"},{"id":366593,"key":"_wccf_of_data_seguir_paquete","value":[]},{"id":366594,"key":"_wccf_of_fecha_entrega","value":"30/08/2019"},{"id":366595,"key":"_wccf_of_id_fecha_entrega","value":"3436"},{"id":366596,"key":"_wccf_of_data_fecha_entrega","value":[]},{"id":366597,"key":"_wccf_of_observaciones_envio","value":""},{"id":366598,"key":"_wccf_of_id_observaciones_envio","value":"2341"},{"id":366599,"key":"_wccf_of_data_observaciones_envio","value":[]},{"id":366600,"key":"_wcpdf_invoice_date","value":"15XXXXXXXX8"},{"id":366601,"key":"_wcpdf_invoice_date_formatted","value":"2019-08-31 21:57:18"},{"id":366602,"key":"_wcpdf_invoice_number","value":"19A000134"},{"id":366603,"key":"_wcpdf_invoice_number_data","value":{"number":134,"formatted_number":"19A000134","prefix":"19","suffix":"A","document_type":"invoice","order_id":3506,"padding":"6"}},{"id":443419,"key":"seguimiento","value":{"transportista":"correos-x","codigo":"32XXXXXXXXXXXXX50","fecha":"2019-08-29"}},{"id":443423,"key":"_wccf_of_cuenta_instagram","value":""},{"id":443424,"key":"_whatsappnotif_checkout_field","value":""},{"id":443425,"key":"_whatsappnewsletter_checkout_field","value":""}],"line_items":[{"id":719,"name":"Collar identificativo para perro personalizado - XS","product_id":2821,"variation_id":2822,"quantity":1,"tax_class":"","subtotal":"9.26","subtotal_tax":"0.00","total":"9.26","total_tax":"0.00","taxes":[],"meta_data":[{"id":5611,"key":"selecciona-talla","value":"XS"},{"id":5612,"key":"_tmcartepo_data","value":[{"mode":"builder","cssclass":"","hidelabelincart":"","hidevalueincart":"","hidelabelinorder":"","hidevalueinorder":"","name":"¿Qué color quieres para la tela?","value":"Rojo","price":0,"section":"5c6f7ae8f1e0e6.13293053","section_label":"¿Qué color quieres para la tela?","percentcurrenttotal":0,"currencies":[],"price_per_currency":{"EUR":""},"quantity":"1","multiple":"1","key":"Rojo_1","use_images":"","use_colors":"","changes_product_image":"","imagesp":"","images":"","color":""},{"mode":"builder","cssclass":"","hidelabelincart":"","hidevalueincart":"","hidelabelinorder":"","hidevalueinorder":"","name":"¿Que quieres agregar?","value":"5) Teléfono + decoraciones","price":0,"section":"5c6f7ae8f1e0e6.28504484","section_label":"¿Que quieres agregar?","percentcurrenttotal":0,"currencies":[],"price_per_currency":{"EUR":""},"quantity":"1","multiple":"1","key":"5) Teléfono + decoraciones_4","use_images":"","use_colors":"","changes_product_image":"","imagesp":"","images":"","color":""},{"mode":"builder","cssclass":"tipografiadelnombre","hidelabelincart":"","hidevalueincart":"","hidelabelinorder":"","hidevalueinorder":"","name":"Teléfono","value":"626448537 ","price":0,"section":"5c6f7ae8f1e158.62582178","section_label":"Teléfono","percentcurrenttotal":0,"currencies":[],"price_per_currency":[],"quantity":"1"},{"mode":"builder","cssclass":"colordelnombre","hidelabelincart":"","hidevalueincart":"","hidelabelinorder":"","hidevalueinorder":"","name":"Color del vinilo","value":"Azul cielo (Ref. 28)","price":0,"section":"5c6f7ae8f1e0f4.91684260","section_label":"Color del vinilo","percentcurrenttotal":0,"currencies":[],"price_per_currency":{"EUR":""},"quantity":"1","multiple":"1","key":"Azul cielo (Ref. 28)_6","use_images":"","use_colors":"","changes_product_image":"","imagesp":"","images":"","color":""},{"mode":"builder","cssclass":"tipografiadelnombre","hidelabelincart":"","hidevalueincart":"","hidelabelinorder":"","hidevalueinorder":"","name":"Tipografía","value":"superstar","price":0,"section":"5c6f7ae8f1e162.34549333","section_label":"Tipografía","percentcurrenttotal":0,"currencies":[],"price_per_currency":[],"quantity":"1"},{"mode":"builder","cssclass":"","hidelabelincart":"","hidevalueincart":"","hidelabelinorder":"","hidevalueinorder":""}]},{"id":5613,"key":"_tm_epo_product_original_price","value":["14"]},{"id":5614,"key":"_tm_epo","value":[1]},{"id":100000,"key":"¿Qué color quieres para la tela?","value":"Rojo"},{"id":100001,"key":"¿Que quieres agregar?","value":"5) Teléfono + decoraciones"},{"id":100002,"key":"Teléfono","value":"6XXXXXXXXX7 "},{"id":100003,"key":"Color del vinilo","value":"Azul cielo (Ref. 28)"},{"id":100004,"key":"Tipografía","value":"superstar"},{"id":100005,"key":"Escoge un estilo","value":"Estrella"}],"sku":"2822","price":9.256198}],"tax_lines":[],"shipping_lines":[{"id":720,"method_title":"Correos Expréss - Paq 24h","method_id":"flat_rate","instance_id":"1","total":"4.55","total_tax":"0.00","taxes":[],"meta_data":[{"id":5620,"key":"Artículos","value":"Collar identificativo para perro personalizado - XS &times; 1"}]}],"fee_lines":[],"coupon_lines":[],"refunds":[],"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https://yourwebsite.com/wp-json/wc/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}],"collection":[{"href":"https://yourwebsite.com/wp-json/wc/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}]}}];
}
```

Comment: I tried this in my code but it just doesn't work.
The JSON code I copied from Postman although I modified the actual data by XXX for data privacy.
The code makes the request through REST API and not webhook, therefore client key and secret key are needed to access the JSON data of the order, and this is working correctly in my spreadsheet document.
The only inconvenience that I am having within the code is to obtain the meta_data of the order as I mentioned.
What I don't understand is because for line_items, coupons and returns I should do it like this but not for meta_data.  @idfurw

Comment: By the way, your code throws me the following error in the spreadsheet: [Ljava.lang.Object;@1a1937f1
In short, we are requesting a value or object but my JSON code the meta_data in an array, and inside it there are other arrays. I have looked at the Log in the console and the log returns an array.
[ 'on',
  '360',
  '1',
  ,
  ,
  { transportista: 'correos-x',
    codigo: '6545216815230115',
    fecha: '2021-08-05' } ]
Therefore I imagine that once the values ​​are recovered with your code, it should make a correct conversion to the data, right? However, how is that done?  @idfurw

Comment: It am saying your example json is not in correct format of json because some lines including closing ] and } are deleted, which I added back in my code. Please compare with your original json to see if my 'recovery' has change the structure of the json itself.

Comment: Does my json run properly with the code snippet?

Comment: Yes, I finally managed to include the data in the google sheet correctly with its code (brackets were missing and thus convert from 1D matrix to 2D matrix to paste the values). @idfurw

Comment: Now the only drawback is that the meta_data key "seguimiento" includes 3 values ​​"transportista" + "codigo" + "fecha". These three values ​​with your code are shown as follows in the Log: { transportista: 'correos-x',
    codigo: '6545216815230115',
    fecha: '2021-08-05' }
And in the spreadsheet it looks like this in a single cell: {codigo=6545216815230115, transportista=correos-x, fecha=2021-08-05}  
So is there a way that the spreadsheet shows each of these three values ​​in a different cell but still in the same row?  @idfurw

Comment: Updated. Please check.

Comment: Now it is perfect !! It works like a charm! I just want to ask you one more question to keep in mind in the future. In case I don't want to have multiple metadata, and just want to get the "seguimiento" meta_data, is the process all the same? Should I just change the constant target to something like this? const target = [{'seguimiento': ['transportista', 'codigo', 'fecha']}];    Really, thank you very much for helping!  @idfurw

Comment: Yes, but of course the output would then start with (the first column will be) the values of 'seguimiento'.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but with the range option and setValues ​​this can be placed in the column wherever I want. I will study your code more in depth to know more in detail how to perform this type of get requests. You have really helped me a lot (I was fighting for two days before asking around). I have marked the answer, I have also voted up. Again, thank you very much.  @idfurw